# What might be the reason of compiler errors when building iOS app for profiling?

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors

When I build my application for running everything is fine, it builds without errors, runs smoothly,
while I build it for profiling I got Swift compiler errors, related to the Charts framework, for ex.:

```
swift:12:54: 'ChartViewDelegate' is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this protocol
swift:13:32: 'BarChartView' is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this class
```

Maybe the reason is in that how I added Charts framework?
I downloaded Charts project, build it and dragged & dropped the project bundle into xCode.
As a result I got in Frameworks group the following:
Charts.framework, Charts-Swift.h, Charts.h

Should I find files(within Charts project what I built separately) with classes that linker/compiler failed to recognize and add them into my project, or some additional project configuration is required?

Can you help me?

**Update:**
when in Settings/scheme I change Profile build configuration from Release to Debug - everything is ok.
And I build my application in Debug mode.
Is the same mode debug/release required for build of application to run and to profile?

Answer (score 0):

You must add `Charts.framework` to every target of your project.

Let me know in the comments if this is the problem.